# Trap Dispatching on Windows

Tags: windows, interrupt

I am actually reading Windows Internals 5th edition and i am enjoying, although isn't a easy book to read and understand.

I am confused about IRQLs and IDT Table.

I read that windows implement custom priorization levels with IRQL and the Plug and Play Manager maps IRQ from devices to IRQL.

Alright, so, IRQLs are used for Software and Hardware interrupts, and for exceptions is used the Exception Dispatch handler.

When one device generates an interrupt, the interrupt controller pass this information to the CPU with the IRQ.

So Windows takes this IRQ and translates to IRQL to schedule when to execute the routine (routine that IDT[IRQ_VALUE] is pointing to?

Is that what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on a very high level.

Everything starts with a kernel trap. Kernel trap handler handles interrupts, exceptions, system service calls and virtual memory pager.

When an interrupt happens (line based - using dedicated pin or message based- writing to an address) windows uses IRQL to determine the priority of the interrupt and uses this to see if the interrupt can be served or not during that time. HAL does the job of translating the IRQ to IRQL. 
It then uses IRQ to get an index of the IDT to find the appropriate ISR routing to invoke. Note there can be multiple ISR associated for a given IRQ. All of them execute in order. 
Each processor has its own IDT so you could potentially have multiple ISR's running at the same time.

Exception dispatch, as I  mentioned before, is also handled by the kernel trap but the procedure for it is different. It usually starts by checking for any exception handlers by stack unwinding, then checking for debugger port etc.